# how do I Instantiating a java class from generic method

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to learn generics in Java. My question is can i instantiating a java class from generic method? I have a method like below

```
private  void  AddAction(ModelBuilding model,TableView table) {         
            table.getItems().add( new ModelBuilding());
        }
```

Here `ModelBuilding()` is my custom java class. When I am trying to make this method generic I am facing problem in instantiating `ModelBuilding()` class. I tried like this and having a compile error.

```
private <E> void  AddAction(E mode,TableView table) {           
            table.getItems().add( new E());
        }
```

How I can make `AddAction(E mode,TableView table)` method generic?

Comment: No, not the way you're doing it. You could pass in a generic factory though, which would be responsible for generating the concrete instance

Comment: You're already taking an `E` instance. Why do you need to create a new one? Did you mean to receive a class (`<E> void  AddAction(Class<E> eclass,TableView table)` and run `eclass.newInstance()`?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele yes. but in that case I have to make my `ModelBuilding()` class generic too. isn't it?

Comment: You can make Generic instance like this. See the doc here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html

Comment: @AritraPaul No, you can still make only the method generic, although it would be a good idea to make the type parameter `E` bounded (to whatever the `.add` method being called takes as type).

Comment: @ErnestKiwele can you give an example please?

Comment: `private <E extends ModelBuilding> addAction(Class<E> eclass, TableView table) {table.getItems().add(eclass.newInstance());}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are passing an instance of `E` to your method, you can create an instance of the same class via reflection:

```
private <E> void AddAction(E mode,TableView table) {           
    table.getItems().add(mode.getClass().newInstance());
}
```

On the other hand, if you are not using the `E` instance passed to your method, it's enough to pass a `Class<E>` in order to create a new instance:

```
private <E> void AddAction(Class<E> clazz,TableView table) {           
    table.getItems().add(clazz.newInstance());
}
```

Either way, you'll have to catch some exceptions that may be thrown by `newInstance()`.

Or, just add the instance passed to your method. The caller of the method will create the instance:

```
private <E> void AddAction(E mode,TableView table) {           
    table.getItems().add(mode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this

```
    private <E> void AddAction(E mode,TableView table)
    {           
       table.getItems().add( mode);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Eran mentioned using reflection to create an instance can trigger exceptions. The javadoc says:

> Note that this method propagates any exception thrown by the nullary
>   constructor, including a checked exception

So when using`newInstance()` you aren't aware of any possible exceptions at compile time.

Furthermore you are limited to use the "nullary constructor". If you want to create an action which has no default constructor or want to use a parametrized constructor you would have to use a reflection call on a `java.lang.reflect.Constuctor`. This all is very fragile regarding code refactoring.

An at least safer approach regarding refactoring is to use a factory method. Instead of passing `Class<E> clazz` to your method, you could pass in for example a `Supplier<E>`. Take a look at the following code:

```
private <E> void AddAction(Supplier<E> factory, TableView table) {
    E mode = factory.get();
    table.getItems().add(mode);
}

private void AddSimpleAction(TableView table) {
    AddAction(SimpleAction::new, table);
}

private void AddDateAwareAction(TableView table) {
    AddAction(() -> new DateAwareAction(new Date()), table);
}

private static class SimpleAction {
    // body
}

private static class DateAwareAction {

    private final Date date;

    public DateAwareAction(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    // body
}
```

If you refactor the constructor of `DateAwareAction` to use a parameter `long dateTimeInMs` you get a syntax error in the method `AddDateAwareAction`. Using reflection to create an instnace this refactoring would stay unnoticed at compile time and would raise an exception at runtime.